# A problem with injecting repository to WorkManager's Worker class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-workmanager

Could you please help me? I have a problem injecting repository and usecase to a Worker using Dagger2.
When it comes to LocationRepository it goes to Result.failure() with the following exception. The related topic unfortunately didn't help.

[image]

My Worker class looks like this. I need a repository to get data from local database and then I need a usecase to push the data to Firebase.
[image]

Somewhere in the internet I found that I need a CustomWorkerFactory. So this the one I have.

[image]

In the App class I initialize WorkManager.

[image]